# Python requests login with website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, session-cookies, build-automation

I can't seem to login to my university website using python requests.session() function. I have tried retrieving all the headers and cookies needed to login but it does not successfully log in with my credentials. It does not show any error but the source code I review after it is supposed to have logged in shows that it is still not logged in. And I was told i need to use the csrf cookie information but I cant seem to dynamically retrieve the csrf cookie data as it raises a KeyError when I try to retrieve like i retrieve the other 2 cookie informations. Please help someone.

All my code is below. I fill the login and password with my credentials, but the rest is the exact code.

```
import requests

with requests.session() as r:
    url = "https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/user/login"
    page = r.get(url)
    aspsessionid = r.cookies["ASPSESSIONID"]
    ouacapply1 = r.cookies["OUACApply1"]
    LOGIN = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    submit = "Log In"
    login_data = dict(ASPSESSIONID=aspsessionid, OUACApply1=ouacapply1, login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD, submitButton=submit)
    header = {"Referer":"https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/user/login", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"}
    logged_in = r.post(url, data=login_data, headers=header)
    new_page = r.get(url="https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/profile/")
    plain_text = new_page.text
    print(plain_text)
```

Comment: using `requests.Session()` you don't have to copy headers and cookies from one request to another.

Comment: `csrf` can be elemeny in `<form>` =, not in cookies. `<form>` may have other hidden fields which you have to use in request. Use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see requests send from browser to server (tab Network)and all parameters in every requests .

Answer (score 1):

I don't have account so I can't test it but it could be something like this.

```
import requests
import bs4
import webbrowser

def display(content):
    # to see this HTML in web browser
    with open('temp.html', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
        webbrowser.open('temp.html')

with requests.session() as r:

    LOGIN = ""
    PASSWORD = ""

    login_url = "https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/user/login"
    profile_url="https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/profile/"

    # session need it only once and it will remember it
    r.headers.update({
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    })

    # load page with form - to get cookies and `csrf` from HTML
    response = r.get(login_url)

    #display(response.content)

    # get `csrf` from HTML
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrf'}).attrs['value']

    print('csrf:', csrf)

    # cookies are not part of form so you don't use in form_data,
    # session will use cookies from previous request so you don't have to copy them
    form_data = {
        'login': LOGIN,
        'password': PASSWORD,
        'submitButton': "Log In",
        'csrf': csrf,
    }

    # send form data to server
    response = r.post(login_url, data=form_data)

    print('status_code:', response.status_code)
    print('history:', response.history)
    print('url:', response.url)

    #display(response.content)

    response = r.get(profile_url)

    display(response.content)
```